# Should I forfeit an agenda when rezzing Archer via Priority Requisition?

Tags: android-netrunner

I've got an unrezzed [Archer](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01101). I score a [Priority Requisition](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01106) and use it to rez Archer. Do I have to forfeit an agenda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you do not need to forfeit an agenda in this case. "forfeit an Agenda" is "an additional cost" to rez Archer, and Priority Requisition instructs the player to "ignor[e] all costs".

Comment: So "an additional cost" is not a part of "all costs"? Can yout cite the rules (FAQ or core book)?

Comment: @Denis Gladkiy I think he were answering a question in the title. I edited question to make in unambiguous.

Comment: @Andrew Vandever please check if your answer is true after the edit.

Comment: It's still true. I went ahead and edited it now to make it more clear. You do not need to forfeit an agenda to rez Archer with Priority Requisition. :) "Additional cost" is included in "all costs".